# Roblox Trello NewCard

Tags: trello, roblox

I have been working the past 5 hours on this script for ROBLOX. This script is supposed to send 2 variables to a trello card. The script would make the trello card and put the information in. Here's my problem, when the user presses send, absolutely nothing happens.. No errors or warnings show up either. 
Links:

Game; https://www.roblox.com/games/2471352403/Inactivity-Notice-C-O

Current Code;

```
local name = script.Parent.NameBox;
local reason = script.Parent.ReasonBox;

script.Parent.send.MouseButton1Click:connect (function()
local TrelloAPI = require(game:GetService("ServerScriptService").TrelloAPI);
local BoardID = TrelloAPI:GetBoardID("Inactivity");
local ListID = TrelloAPI:GetListID("Notices",BoardID)
local NewCard = TrelloAPI:AddCard("Inactivity Notice Incoming...","Notice 
from:"..name"\n Reason:"..reason"",ListID)
wait(5)
game.Players.LocalPlayer:kick("Sent!")
end)
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Well to start im hoping that TrelloAPI Is defined as an API someone has made for the game, as Roblox has removed all HTTP Connections to Trello.

Also I believe it may not be working due to the space in between here

```
connect (function()
```

-- Read This Stuff Below as it is Important --

You should have done everything correct other than that, I have visited your game and I know that it is a Script and not a LocalScript... As far as that goes I don't think Roblox has an official API according to the documentation for Trello, if they do it is outdated and does not work.

Also I Googled TrelloAPI for Roblox, and the question was marked as off topic, Unless you manually add a TrelloAPI there is not one in Roblox.

Also it doesn't look you are calling a function to send the Data either way there should be some sort of HttpFunction so that the API could communicate with Trello.

EDIT: Error here kick() use Kick() there is no Trello API for Roblox still